# Running Spark on the slave node (YARN) doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, master-slave

I can run SparkPi example on the master node, but when I try the same command
"spark-submit --class SparkPi --master yarn-client sparkpi.jar 10"
on the slave node, I got an error:

```
2015-05-19 14:05:44,881 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing view acls to: maintainer
2015-05-19 14:05:44,886 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Changing modify acls to: maintainer
2015-05-19 14:05:44,887 INFO  [main] spark.SecurityManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(maintainer); users with modify permissions: Set(maintainer)
2015-05-19 14:05:45,389 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] slf4j.Slf4jLogger (Slf4jLogger.scala:applyOrElse(80)) - Slf4jLogger started
2015-05-19 14:05:45,443 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] Remoting (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Starting remoting
2015-05-19 14:05:45,641 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] Remoting (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave2.com:33055]
2015-05-19 14:05:45,644 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] Remoting (Slf4jLogger.scala:apply$mcV$sp(74)) - Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave2.com:33055]
2015-05-19 14:05:45,653 INFO  [main] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33055.
2015-05-19 14:05:45,674 INFO  [main] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering MapOutputTracker
2015-05-19 14:05:45,688 INFO  [main] spark.SparkEnv (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering BlockManagerMaster
2015-05-19 14:05:45,707 INFO  [main] storage.DiskBlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20150519140545-c81b
2015-05-19 14:05:45,712 INFO  [main] storage.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - MemoryStore started with capacity 265.4 MB
2015-05-19 14:05:46,205 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-05-19 14:05:46,408 INFO  [main] spark.HttpFileServer (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-e95a2b5b-efea-41eb-93b9-0a9f7d6f6701
2015-05-19 14:05:46,413 INFO  [main] spark.HttpServer (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Starting HTTP Server
2015-05-19 14:05:46,477 INFO  [main] server.Server (Server.java:doStart(272)) - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-05-19 14:05:46,499 INFO  [main] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStart(338)) - Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:52737
2015-05-19 14:05:46,500 INFO  [main] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 52737.
2015-05-19 14:05:46,790 INFO  [main] server.Server (Server.java:doStart(272)) - jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2015-05-19 14:05:46,805 INFO  [main] server.AbstractConnector (AbstractConnector.java:doStart(338)) - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
2015-05-19 14:05:46,805 INFO  [main] util.Utils (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
2015-05-19 14:05:46,808 INFO  [main] ui.SparkUI (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Started SparkUI at http://slave2.com:4040
2015-05-19 14:05:47,058 INFO  [main] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Added JAR file:/home/maintainer/myjars/sparkpi.jar at http://[ip]:52737/jars/sparkpi.jar with timestamp 1432033547057
2015-05-19 14:05:47,190 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-05-19 14:09:45,861 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
**2015-05-19 14:09:47,067 INFO  [main] ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(842)) - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-05-19 14:09:48,068 INFO  [main] ipc.Client (Client.java:handleConnectionFailure(842)) - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...**
```

Comment: What is the `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname`  in yarn config?

Comment: @RemusRusanu, do you mean yarn-site.xml? there is no such parameter

Comment: Set it to the RM hostname, on RM node and all NM nodes too.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I did it (added a property yarn.resourcemanager.hostname with the value mymaster.com in yarn-site.xml in all the nodes), but nothing changed :( I also tried ip address instead of the name, no luck again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from specifying `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` property in `yarn-site.xml`, it's also necessary to propagate configuration files to workers.

It might be done with this line (before running `spark-submit`):

```
export SPARK_YARN_DIST_FILES=$(ls $HADOOP_CONF_DIR* | sed 's#^#file://#g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

If everything's configured correctly, you'll see RM hostname instead of `0.0.0.0` in this line:

```
2015-05-19 14:05:47,190 INFO  [main] client.RMProxy (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
```

Comment: thank you, it helped to handle the error mentioned above but now I have another error: 
    2015-05-25 11:10:51,982 WARN  [Timer-0] cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler (Logging.scala:logWarning(71)) - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
I tried to add parameters to my command "spark-submit --class SparkPi --master yarn-client --executor-memory 512m --driver-memory 512m sparkexamples.jar 10" but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting correct values for `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` fixed the issue.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/your-path/hadoop/conf
```